# Is it true that given a matrix $A$, $A$ has L.I columns/rows if and only if $\text {det}(A)\neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true that given a matrix $A$, $A$ has L.I columns/rows if and only if $\text {det}(A)=0$?

This is my question I think the statement is something like the above but I'm not 100% sure. If anyone could give me the correct statement and maybe some reasoning (not necessarily proof) as to why this would be the case I would appreciate it.

I'm more than willing to give my input but I'm quite stuck at the moment so have not a lot to offer unfortunately.

Thanks.

Comment: It's supposed to be "$\iff \det(A) \ne 0$".  I try to motivate this geometrically [in this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297451/how-was-the-determinant-of-matrices-generalized-for-matrices-bigger-than-2-tim/1297508#1297508).

Comment: Only if $A$ is a square matrix.

Comment: ^ Oh right.  That too. :)

Comment: Yes of course I meant does not equal zero apologies. I will take a look over the answer now. Could you also explain to me if L.I rows is the same as L.I columns I think it would be but I'm not fully confident.

Comment: There is a theorem which states that the column rank = the row rank of a matrix.  This implies that a **square** matrix with L.I. columns will have L.I. rows.

Comment: Unless there's something else you'd like to know, I'm going to vote to close this because asking "Is this statement correct" warrants only a one line answer and I don't think this question will be of use to anyone else.

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/585143